# chat_bot apk with kivy tflearn tensorflow

Tags: build, sdk, gradlew

kivy
gradlew build error
packageDebug failed
gradle build is outdated
sdk is depreceated and does nothing
[screenshot of error from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THutv.jpg)

here is code and error link:
https://github.com/bidursapkota00/chat_bot

Comment: You can attach the full error `log`, your `buildozer.spec` and how to tell how you installed `buildozer` and as far as I know, there is no recipe for building applications using `tensorflow` yet

Comment: @Neizvestnyj              https://github.com/bidursapkota00/chat_bot

Comment: I ask you, always attach the log in one file, you can in txt format, working with png is very inconvenient

Comment: In general, you need to create a recipe for tensorflow, now p4a does not have it

Comment: @Neizvestnyj : ok i will add log file from now on. I created main.py file just with box layout and text layout and tried to build the app. it failed to patch java. This error was in the previous log with Machine Learning. so, error seems to be "failed to Patch java".

Comment: how to solve that

Comment: Where did you attach the log?

Comment: @Neizvestnyj added log file

Comment: FULL LOG FILE...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tensorflow is not yet supported by kivy.